# Python Windows Run Bash Commands

Tags: python-3.x, windows, bash

I am on a Windows computer, and I have the Ubuntu command line installed. I can access this through the `bash` command in the Windows command line. I figured I could just call this command through Python:

```
import os

os.system('bash')
```

However, the code simply freezes and does not do anything. Is there any way for me to use this bash terminal in Windows using Python? any help would be appreciated!

Comment: That's basically the same as running `cmd /c bash` in CMD. It works fine for me..

Comment: I understand. However, using `cmd /c bash` in Python's `os.system` did not work and gave me the same problem

Comment: Oh... I am using an IDE. I can't believe I let that slip my mind! Thank you for pointing that out. Is there a way I can pass commands to this? For example, can I call the bash shell and call `ls` on it?

Comment: Do you want to interact with the shell or just get the output of a single command?

Comment: Get the output of a single command

Comment: Use the subprocess module. For example: `import subprocess;` `p = subprocess.run(['bash', '-c', 'ls /'], capture_output=True, encoding='utf-8', creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW);` `print(p.stdout)`. This sets a specific encoding because WSL uses UTF-8 instead of the default system ANSI codepage. It uses the `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` creation flag to ensure that a new  text session is created that will never show a window; it's strictly a background command.

Comment: For an interactive shell, run `subprocess.run(['bash'], creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)`. This ensures that a new text session is created that has a visible window. `os.system('start bash')` should also work because CMD's `start` command defaults to using `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`.